# How to pass the value of a label in my TableCell to the TableViewController on the click of a button in the TableCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

So, I have a ViewController(PledgeViewController) with a UITableView and another file called PledgeTableViewCell.swift which is a UITableCell file. When someone clicks a button(plsBtn) in the PledgeTableViewCell.swift, I have set up a closure which feeds back into the PledgeViewController and I handle my operations from there. What I want to do now is this:

When someone clicks the plsBtn in the PledgeTableViewCell, I'm handling that action in the PledgeViewController. But I want to read the value of a label in the TableViewCell at that indexPath and send it to the PledgeViewController for further calculations. Can I do this with the closure itself or is there another method? Thanks!

PledgeTableViewCell.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase


class PledgeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var plusBtnAction: ((Any) -> Void)?
    var minusBtnAction: ((Any) -> Void)?

    @IBOutlet weak var rewardAmtLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticketClasslabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticketDescLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var ticketCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var minusBtn: UIButton!

    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var currentID = ""
    var ticket_count: Int = 0
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    @IBAction func minusBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        if var tickCount = Int(ticketCountLabel.text!) {

            if(tickCount > 0)
            {
                tickCount -= 1
                ticketCountLabel.text = String(tickCount)
            }
        }

        self.minusBtnAction?(sender)
    }

    @IBAction func plusBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {


        if var tickCount = Int(ticketCountLabel.text!) {

//I WANT TO SEND THIS 'TICKCOUNT' TO THE PLEDGEVIEWCONTROLLER
            tickCount += 1
            ticketCountLabel.text = String(tickCount)
        }


        self.plusBtnAction?(sender)

    }


}
```

PledgeViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase

class PledgeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


    var getID: String!
    var rewards = [Rewards]()
    var ticket_count: Int = 0
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    var rewardID: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var pledgeAmtLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var RewardChooseTable: UITableView!
    @IBAction func pledgeBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        //get the text from the label and run all the checks to see if the tickets are available

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        /*  myIndex = indexPath.row

         finalId = idTable[myIndex]
         let story = stories[indexPath.row]
         ArtcallID = story.id

         performSegue(withIdentifier: "singleArtcall", sender: self)
         */
        let reward = rewards[indexPath.row]
        let id = reward.rewardID
        reward.countUp()

        print("The reward that was touched is: " + id )
        print("One of the buttons were touched")
    }

    let RewardRef = Database.database().reference().child("Rewards")


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return rewards.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TakePledgeCell", for: indexPath) as! PledgeTableViewCell
        let reward = rewards[indexPath.row]
        cell.reward = reward
        cell.currentID = getID
        rewardID = reward.rewardID

        cell.plusBtnAction = { sender in

            let reward = self.rewards[indexPath.row]
            cell.reward = reward
            let local_id = reward.rewardID

            self.ref=Database.database().reference().child("Fund_Project_Request").child(self.getID).child(self.userID).child(local_id).child("Ticket_count")


            self.ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value

                if snapshot.value is NSNull{
                    self.ticket_count = 0
                    self.ticket_count += 1
                    self.ref.setValue(self.ticket_count)
                }

                else{
                    self.ticket_count = snapshot.value as! Int
                    self.ticket_count += 1
                    self.ref.setValue(self.ticket_count)
                }


            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

           Database.database().reference().child("Rewards").child(self.getID).child(local_id).child("reward_ticket_amount").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value
                let reward_amt = snapshot.value as! Int

                self.pledgeAmtLabel.text = String(reward_amt)

            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            // Do whatever you want from your button here.
        }



        cell.minusBtnAction = { sender in

            let reward = self.rewards[indexPath.row]
            cell.reward = reward
            let local_id = reward.rewardID

        self.ref=Database.database().reference().child("Fund_Project_Request").child(self.getID).child(self.userID).child(local_id).child("Ticket_count")
            self.ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // Get user value

                if snapshot.value is NSNull{

                }

                else{

                    self.ticket_count = snapshot.value as! Int
                    if(self.ticket_count != 0)
                    {
                        self.ticket_count -= 1
                        self.ref.setValue(self.ticket_count)
                    }
                }


            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }



        }



        return cell

    }



    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        RewardRef.child(getID).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.rewards.removeAll()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                let childSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
                let reward = Rewards(snapshot: childSnapshot)
                self.rewards.insert(reward, at: 0)
            }

            self.RewardChooseTable.reloadData()
        })

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("The id received from the SingleViewControl is:" + getID)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the label value in the closure itself along with sender.

```
class PledgeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var plusBtnAction: ((String) -> Void)?
    var minusBtnAction: ((String) -> Void)?



     @IBAction func minusBtn(_ sender: Any) {

          if var tickCount = Int(ticketCountLabel.text!) {

            if(tickCount > 0)
            {
                tickCount -= 1
                ticketCountLabel.text = String(tickCount)

            }
            self.minusBtnAction?(tickCount)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func plusBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if var tickCount = Int(ticketCountLabel.text!) {

//I WANT TO SEND THIS 'TICKCOUNT' TO THE PLEDGEVIEWCONTROLLER
            tickCount += 1
            ticketCountLabel.text = String(tickCount)
            self.plusBtnAction?(ticketCount)
        }

       }
    }
```

in `cellForRow:` method in `PledgeViewController`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TakePledgeCell", for: indexPath) as! PledgeTableViewCell
        .....
        cell.plusBtnAction = { labelText in
           //handle labelText here
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain further?

Comment: And how would I receive it in the PledgeViewController?

Comment: added code please check. you can handle inside the closure in celForRow

Comment: The use of `sender` and `Any` makes no sense here. The `plusBtnAction` and `minusBtnAction `closures should pass the cell and text, not the sender.

Comment: why it should pass cell reference?, its already in cellForRow which gives the cell.

Comment: Hey so my other question is, you're defining a string in the closure, how can you pass an Integer?

Comment: I'm not receiving the String in the PledgeViewController

Comment: Put breakpoint in your cell and view controller and test.